# How much exactly do debt collectors usually pay for medical debt?

Tags: united-states, healthcare, debt-collection, medical-bill

Just read the book [Never Pay The First Bill](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0593190009) by Marshall Allen. It was eye-opening and confirmed a lot of my suspicions about the relationship between health insurers and healthcare providers.

This book, among others, repeatedly cites that debt collectors buy medical debt for "sometimes pennies on the dollar".

Does anyone know of any resources, datasets, anything, that might paint a more quantitative picture of this? I am wondering, how many pennies on the dollar? Does this vary for different procedures, patients etc? For example a Medicaid patient vs a Cadillac plan patient?

A corollary question would be: How do healthcare providers decide to sue for debt? Are they allowed to pull your tax transcript and credit score like lenders are? Or is it somewhat random?

Comment: There's a book? It's just one sentence: "American healthcare system is insane", you don't need a whole book for that...

Comment: Depends on the collector, depends on the case. I don't think w general answer exists, and it really isn't a personal finance question since there's very little you can do about it except a oid getting into that situation. See past answers for why the idea of buying your own debt at a discount doesn't work.

Comment: @keshlam "buying your own debt at a discount" is not exactly what I'm going for here. More of "figuring out what the debt collector paid, and offering just above that". Which I guess amounts to the same thing. At any rate would you mind linking me to some of those past answers?

Comment: Look for other questions tagged  "debt collection" (https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/debt-collection).

Comment: Your title is confusing. You want to know "exactly", but also "usually". Which is it?

Answer (score 4):

The original debtor asks as much as they possibly can get when selling the loan. The debt collector only offers a tiny amount because it is a major hassle and expense to collect money that people have already been unable or unwilling to pay, and many of those debts will have to be written off as losses. The worse the past history of payment, the lower the potential value and they less they'll pay for the debt. Offering them something just barely better than writing it off as a loss probably won't interest them.

Selling the debt is a recognition that the hospital doesn't think they're going to be able to collect without being so rude that it damages their reputation, and so takes a pittance as "better than nothing" and hands off to someone who is willing to be that rude in order to try to profit on the deal. And that latter party is who you're now dealing with.

If you are asking whether the hospital might be willing to negotiate a  payment for more than the collector would pay, or the collector might accept a pittance for a fast easy profit... They really, really don't want to set that precedent. The last thing either wants is to encourage people to try paying less than they owe.

This is not a path toward paying less yourself. It is not a path toward avoiding a MAJOR hit on your credit rating.

The hospital *might* be willing to work with you on financing the debt so you can pay it over a longer time. But the interest rate you're going to be offered will reflect how much confidence folks have that you will make those payments... and if you're already in default, don't expect them to be very enthusiastic about the idea.

Comment: **"*They really, really don't want to set that precedent.*"** - this is the key. There's a distance between the collectors and the hospital that the OP is trying to bridge here, and there's absolutely no motivation for either of them to let that happen.